# verdaccio publish new package

Tags: npm-publish, verdaccio

OS OpenSuse 15.2  I have trouble with publihing new packages to local npm proxy

Verdaccio version 5.1.0

1. I have installed verdaccio from npm
2. Added user verdaccio  :  `id verdaccio uid=1001(verdaccio) gid=100(users) группы=100(users)`
3. Added to config storage path params :

   ```
      storage: /npm/storage
      # path to a directory with plugins to include
      plugins: /npm/plugins
   ```
4. Run it

   ```
      warn --- config file  - /home/verdaccio/.config/verdaccio/config.yaml
      warn --- Plugin successfully loaded: verdaccio-htpasswd
      warn --- Plugin successfully loaded: verdaccio-audit
      warn --- http address - http://172.16.4.76:1234/ - verdaccio/5.1.0
   ```
5. Add npm user and set npm manager to register local proxy

   ```
   Username: verdaccio
   Password: 
   Email: (this IS public) 
   Logged in as verdaccio on http://172.16.4.76:1234/.
   ```

Then I cd to js module and do :

````
```# npm publish --registry http://172.16.4.76:1234/
````

Got an error :
(npm )

````
```npm notice 
npm notice   easyrabbit@1.0.0
npm notice === Tarball Contents === 
npm notice 418B  package.json        
npm notice 1B    README.md           
npm notice 1.5kB class.easyrabbit.mjs
npm notice === Tarball Details === 
npm notice name:          easyrabbit                              
npm notice version:       1.0.0                                   
npm notice package size:  938 B                                   
npm notice unpacked size: 1.9 kB                                  
npm notice shasum:        9f758fe3b7076efb131482242bccab92e6d12218
npm notice integrity:     sha512-rFP+zMQlRFZhB[...]MQmtD0g1Y6u9Q==
npm notice total files:   3                                       
npm notice 
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - PUT http://172.16.4.76:1234/easyrabbit - no such package available
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'easyrabbit@1.0.0' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-06-05T11_27_47_111Z-debug.log
````

On verdaccio side :

````
``` 
   http --- 172.16.4.76 requested 'GET /npm'
   (node:12088) [DEP0106] DeprecationWarning: crypto.createDecipher is deprecated.
   info --- auth/allow_action: access granted to: undefined
   info --- allowed access for npm
   info --- making request: 'GET https://registry.npmjs.org/npm'
   http --- 200, req: 'GET https://registry.npmjs.org/npm' (streaming)
   http --- 200, req: 'GET https://registry.npmjs.org/npm', bytes: 0/15211570
   http --- 200, user: verdaccio(172.16.4.76), req: 'GET /npm', bytes: 0/4171881
   http --- 172.16.4.76 requested 'GET /npm'
   info --- auth/allow_action: access granted to: undefined
   info --- allowed access for npm
   http --- 172.16.4.76 requested 'GET /-/whoami'
   http --- 304, user: verdaccio(172.16.4.76), req: 'GET /-/whoami', bytes: 0/0
   http --- 200, user: verdaccio(172.16.4.76), req: 'GET /npm', bytes: 0/4171881
   http --- 172.16.4.76 requested 'POST /-/v1/login'
   http --- 404, user: verdaccio(172.16.4.76), req: 'POST /-/v1/login', bytes: 18/150
   http --- 172.16.4.76 requested 'PUT /-/user/org.couchdb.user:verdaccio'
   http --- 201, user: verdaccio(172.16.4.76), req: 'PUT 
   /-/user/org.couchdb.user:verdaccio', bytes: 134/110
   http --- 192.168.3.105 requested 'GET /'
   http --- 304, user: null(192.168.3.105), req: 'GET /', bytes: 0/0
   http --- 192.168.3.105 requested 'GET /-/verdaccio/packages'
   http --- 304, user: null(192.168.3.105), req: 'GET /-/verdaccio/packages', bytes: 0/0
   http --- 172.16.4.76 requested 'PUT /easyrabbit'
   info --- auth/allow_action: access granted to: undefined
   info --- verdaccio is allowed publish for easyrabbit
   info --- auth/allow_action: access granted to: undefined
   info --- verdaccio allowed unpublish for easyrabbit
   http --- 404, user: verdaccio(172.16.4.76), req: 'PUT /easyrabbit', error: no such 
   package available
````

What do I wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

I've had this error two days ago. I tried everything, even updated to verdaccio 5.1.

My solution: in my package.json, there was a field "deprecated" set to false. I don't know how this got there, but once I removed it, I could publish again. Check your package.json and remove some fields you do not need, maybe you'll get lucky. Verdaccio error messages on the server do not mention anything about a malformed package.json.

Comment: Thanks, but I don`t gave field "deprecated" in my package.json. But also will try check it again

Comment: Maybe it's a specific field. Idk. But there's a good chance your package.json is malformed in some way

Comment: Thanks, I`ll try to check

Comment: Thanks. Checking package.json was a good idea. Everything work!

Comment: glad to hear it! consider accepting my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

One scenario I've found that can ostensibly cause this issue:

- Deploy the Verdaccio image in a compose-stack:

  - stood up with an **empty** package-database ✔️ (ergo your solution if you're doing the below)
  - stood up with a pre-existing volume mapped package database ❌

    - _if you look deeper you'll see verdaccio log this message: `error--- indexer has failed on add item` (presuming there is some kind of ownership issue here...)